# How do you put two different text in a UIButton

Tags: swift, uibutton

I'm trying to create a UIButton in Swift that has two different setTitles or just two sets of text in it. Is this is even possible? If not what is the best option on how to make a button have two different titles in it? The reason why I ask is because I'm pulling two different queries that have data showing a job description and company. I can only can set a job name with the setTitle but I dont know how to also input the company name in that same button. Here is a visual of what I'm trying to achieve. Anything will help thanks!

[image]

Comment: Rather than trying to use the setTitle method of a standard button, you could create a custom button that is a subclass of UIbutton.  You could then do anything you want in the drawRect method including drawing text at different locations with a variety of fonts.

Comment: Thats pretty neat I never knew that! Can you give me an example? I'm still learning because swift is new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only example I have for you is an OS X NSButton subclass, but the change to a UIButton shouldn't be difficult.

Note that the drawRect code is just like you'd do it in an NSView (or UIView). From the picture you posted, I think you actually already know how to do this.

The code:

```
import Foundation
import AppKit


class WispSquareButton : NSButton
{
    var buttonTitle:String = String();

// *************************************************** Draw Rect ******************************************************

override func drawRect(dirtyRect:NSRect)
{
    let context = NSGraphicsContext.currentContext()!.CGContext       // Get the context

    let rgbColorspace:CGColorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB() // Define a color space variable
    let nsBounds:NSRect = self.bounds                                 // Get the bounds
    let cgBounds:CGRect = NSRectToCGRect(nsBounds)                    // Sets the graphics bounds

    // Top Side Color
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.41568627, 0.69803922, 0.95686275, 1.0)

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0.0, 0.0)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, cgBounds.size.width, 0.0)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, cgBounds.size.width * 0.95, cgBounds.size.height * 0.15)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, cgBounds.size.width * 0.05, cgBounds.size.height * 0.15)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 0.0, 0.0)
    CGContextFillPath(context)


    // Right Side
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.03529412, 0.20784314, 0.38823529, 1.0)

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, cgBounds.size.width, 0.0)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, cgBounds.size.width, cgBounds.size.height)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, cgBounds.size.width * 0.95, cgBounds.size.height * 0.85)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, cgBounds.size.width * 0.95, cgBounds.size.height * 0.15)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, cgBounds.size.width, 0.0)
    CGContextFillPath(context)

    // Left Side
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.41568627, 0.69803922, 0.95686275, 1.0)

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0.0, 0.0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, cgBounds.size.width * 0.05, cgBounds.size.height * 0.15)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, cgBounds.size.width * 0.05, cgBounds.size.height * 0.85)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 0.0, cgBounds.size.height);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 0.0, 0.0)
    CGContextFillPath(context)

    // Bottom Side
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.03529412, 0.20784314, 0.38823529, 1.0)

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0.0, cgBounds.size.height)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, cgBounds.size.width, cgBounds.size.height)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, cgBounds.size.width * 0.95, cgBounds.size.height * 0.85)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, cgBounds.size.width * 0.05, cgBounds.size.height * 0.85)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 0.0, cgBounds.size.height)
    CGContextFillPath(context)

    // Center
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.24117647, 0.53333333, 0.82941176, 1.0)

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, cgBounds.size.width * 0.05, cgBounds.size.height * 0.15)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, cgBounds.size.width * 0.95, cgBounds.size.height * 0.15)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, cgBounds.size.width * 0.95, cgBounds.size.height * 0.85)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, cgBounds.size.width * 0.05, cgBounds.size.height * 0.85)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, cgBounds.size.width * 0.05, cgBounds.size.height * 0.15)
    CGContextFillPath(context);

    if(buttonTitle != "")
    {
        // ********************************************* Set up the Text
        let textSize:CGFloat = cgBounds.size.height * 0.65
        let textCenterY:CGFloat = cgBounds.size.height / 2.0
        let boundsCenterX:CGFloat = cgBounds.size.width / 2.0

         // Set the text matrix.
        let textTransform:CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformMake(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, textTransform)

        // Create a color that will be added as an attribute to the attrString for button text.
        let buttonTextColorComponents:[CGFloat] = [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ]
        let buttonTextColor:CGColorRef = CGColorCreate(rgbColorspace, buttonTextColorComponents)

        // Create a color that will be added as an attribute to the attrString for invisible text.
        let invisibleTextColorComponents:[CGFloat] = [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ];
        let invisibleColor:CGColorRef = CGColorCreate(rgbColorspace, invisibleTextColorComponents);

        // Create a font for text.
        let stringFontName:CFStringRef = CFStringCreateWithCString(kCFAllocatorDefault, "AppleCasual",  kCFStringEncodingASCII)
        let stringFont:CTFontRef = CTFontCreateWithName(stringFontName, textSize, nil)

        // Create a mutable attributed string with a max length of 0 for normal text.
        var attrString:CFMutableAttributedStringRef = CFAttributedStringCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0)

        // Create a path which will bound the area where you will be drawing text.
        var invisibleTextPath:CGMutablePathRef = CGPathCreateMutable()

        // Create a path which will bound the area where you will be drawing text.
        var buttonTextPath:CGMutablePathRef = CGPathCreateMutable()

        // Center the Title

        // Get Title Length
        var titleLength:CFIndex = CFStringGetLength(buttonTitle)

        // Measure the string length
        var invisibleTextBounds:CGRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, cgBounds.size.width * 2.0, textSize * 1.3)
        CGPathAddRect(invisibleTextPath, nil, invisibleTextBounds)

        // Copy the title into attrString
        CFAttributedStringReplaceString (attrString, CFRangeMake(0, 0), buttonTitle)

        // Set the color and font of the invisibleText
        CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(attrString, CFRangeMake(0, titleLength), kCTForegroundColorAttributeName, invisibleColor)
        CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(attrString, CFRangeMake(0, titleLength), kCTFontAttributeName, stringFont)

        // Create the framesetter with the attributed string.
        var framesetter:CTFramesetterRef = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attrString);

        var frame:CTFrameRef = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), invisibleTextPath, nil);

        // Draw the invisible string
        CTFrameDraw(frame, context);

        var endingTextPoint:CGPoint = CGContextGetTextPosition(context);

        // Draw the Visible Text
        // Set a rectangular path.

        var textBounds:CGRect = CGRectMake(boundsCenterX - (endingTextPoint.x / 2.0), textCenterY, cgBounds.size.width, textSize * 1.3)
        CGPathAddRect(buttonTextPath, nil, textBounds)

        // Copy the textString into attrString
        CFAttributedStringReplaceString (attrString, CFRangeMake(0, titleLength), buttonTitle)

        // Set the color and font.
        CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(attrString, CFRangeMake(0, titleLength), kCTForegroundColorAttributeName, buttonTextColor)
        CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(attrString, CFRangeMake(0, titleLength), kCTFontAttributeName, stringFont)

        // Create the framesetter with the attributed string.
        framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attrString)

        // Create a frame.
        frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), buttonTextPath, nil)

        // Draw the specified frame in the given context.
        CTFrameDraw(frame, context);

    }

CGContextFlush(context);

}

// ***************************************************** Set Title ****************************************************

func setTitle(aString:String)
{
    buttonTitle = aString;
}

}
```

I use the button by dragging a custom view into a window, and in the identity inspector set the view's class to "WispSquareButton".  I declare an IBOutlet to the view:

```
@IBOutlet var wispSquareButton:WispSquareButton!
```

And connect it in IB.

To set the button title I use:

```
wispSquareButton.setTitle("Square Button")
wispSquareButton.display()
```

This is what the button looks like:

[image]

To draw a second line of text I might add an additional instance variable:

```
var buttonTitle:String = String()
var buttonTitle2:String = String()
```

Change my setTitle function to:

```
func setTitle(aString:String, aString2:String)
{
    buttonTitle = aString;
    buttonTitle2 = aString2
}
```

and in the drawRect function repeat the buttonTitle drawing code for buttonTitle2 (changing it's location of course). I could also change all the font attributes (font style, size and color) for buttonTitle2.